# Using Firebase .getDownloadURL() Is the image display charged?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm using Firebase on Flutter, and I have a question.
I use the .getDownloadURL() function to get the URL of the image uploaded to the FireStore and display the image in the app as a NetworkImage(url) function.
At this time, will the firebase cost be charged?

**Summary:
flutter > .getDownloadURL() > NetworkImage(url)
I'd like to know if the cost will be incurred at this time.**

Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, beyond the free plan, downloading data from Cloud Storage through Firebase is a charged operation.

As shown in the [Firebase pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing), you will be charged for the number of download operations, and for the amount of data downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase has two pricing levels. The first one incorporates a limited Free tier, and it’s an excellent option for development and small applications. The second tier works on a pay as you grow model, and it’s ideal for production applications. Hopefully this will help you.

**Spark Plan** (Firebase free tier) is a basic plan offering 1 GB total storage, 20K writes/day, 50K reads/day, and 20K deleted/day

**Blaze Plan** (paid) is a pay as you go plan charging $0.18/GB for database storage, $0.026/GB for application storage, and additional charges for database operations, data transfer, etc.